# How do I package node.js app into single file (without bundling node.js itself)?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to deliver a node.js server-side application (not browser) as a single file that contains all my code and node_modules. Well, it can be a few files, but I'd like to avoid shipping 10,000+ files, that are usually in node_modules.

I've used solutions like [pkg](https://npmjs.com/pkg), but I don't need an executable that has node.js bundled. I'd rather ship node.js separately and only have a bundle with code. This would be especially useful as I need to ship a few applications and don't need each of them to contain a copy of node.js.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: install node modules globally ,will make your burden less

Comment: You don't need to deliver node_modules, this can be done with package lock file and `npm i`. A bundler like Webpack won't work well for Node app. That's a use case for containers. Check Docker.

Comment: @estus I need to be able to deploy to locations which could be offline. Also doing `npm install` doesn't make me not ship those 10K files - they just come from a different location.

Comment: Seems like a perfect case for Docker then. I don't think that bundled node is a problem, the footprint isn't that big. pkg is a nice thing but I have doubts that it's well-suited for production.

Comment: Forgot to mention, as for the question you asked, I'm not sure if there's a good way to do this, primarily because a lot of packages are platform-dependent and and an app packaged on one platform may not work on another, especially if there are native modules. Any way, you could try to use bundledDependencies and then `npm pack`.